# Attaching specific EBS volume given Batch job details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, aws-batch

I have a sequence of data processing jobs (a pipeline) that I am executing using AWS Batch, and I would like some of these jobs to share the same EBS volumes. I dynamically create a new EBS volume specifically for each pipeline of Batch jobs to be executed. I can list, attach and mount EBS volumes using a script that runs at instance’s startup, written in the `user data` field of the Launch Templates used by my Batch Compute Environments.

To be clear, in the `user data` script of the Launch Template I can run commands such as:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes
aws ec2 attach-volume
```

My problem is: I want to be able to choose, among a list of available EBS volumes, which one should be attached to the instance running a particular job. This will be known at the batch job submission time, but I can’t find a way to get access to this information at the ec2 startup time, i.e. within the `user data` script.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

obs.: I would like to avoid using EFS, because of its costs.

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your case, but could you use tags to loosely couple the volumes to the pipelines? In your userdata you can get tags from the instance itself or search EBS for volumes with matching tag(/s)

Comment: that’s an interesting approach @MisterSmith, I can definitely tag the EBS volumes with pipeline-specific info, but when I tried setting `propagateTags=True` when submitting a new Batch job, apparently this tag does not get propagated all the way to the EC2 instance itself… it seems to be propagated to the ECS Task, but I can’t find a way to identify from within the instance, which ecs task created it

Comment: I think with `aws batch describe-job-definitions ...` (or maybe `describe-compute-environments`) and the environment variables from batch (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_env_vars.html) you can get the tag, then search for the vol and attach? (And update IAM role to grant suitable batch access :)